# How can I increase the default size 16px from Jquery-UI icon set?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to increase the size of JQuery icons from 16 to 24px.

Comment: You cannot magically add 320 pixels to an icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im pretty sure that the icons are packed into a css sprite grid therefor cant be bigger ... the only thing i could think of is adding a margin around it but then the icon would still be small in the middle of a bigger empty space.

or even opening the sprite and making bigger icons ! ;)

Here what i would try (you would still have to edit your sprite sheet but im sure soneone descent with photoshop can make it easy :

```
function getPos(X,Y,Size)
{
    var posJson = { posX:0,posY:0 };
    posJson.posX = X*-Size;
    posJson.posY = Y*-Size;
    return posJson;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Pos = getPos(0,1,16);
    $(".ui-icon-carat-1-n").css("background-position",Pos.posX+"px "+Pos.posY+"px");
});
```

Comment: @lil'monkey you are right they are in a sprite, I figured also the margin solution but it doesnt affect the size as you mentioned. I ll go the manual way of resizing.

Comment: If ever u edit the size of the icons in the sprite it could be nice to write down all the steps you had to do in the code. and post it down cuz i noticed that theres quite a few ppl asking that quetions on multiple forums.

Comment: @lil'monkey I have had a look at the sprite but in order to make the whole thing work i have to be really accurate about the resizing thing and the margins besides that I ll have to recalculate every position for every icon in the sprite which is not convinient because i use several themes and change them dynamically. I ll see if I can figure out a way to write an automation so each icon theme will be converted to a bigger one. Any precalculations are more than welcome.

Comment: i jsut opened the css to check it out and i understand what u mean now ... background positions would have to be set in the code to be dynamic and all the sprite grids would have to be changed (perfectly) Could you resize the background-position on the ready state? cuz then you could make a function that return the positions passing icon index X and Y and the icon size function ex : getPos(0,0,24) returning { posX:0,posY:0 }... and then jsut overwrite the CSS with those positions

Comment: edited my answer with a sample of code i would try where 16 would be 24 in your case

Comment: i also checked with my designer friend who said you can stretch the sprite in photoshop really easily we tried it with a sprite that was 16icon/15 so 256px/240px ... changed it to 24px per icon took us 10 sec and was done and the icons were still looking pretty good

Answer (score 6):

You can add a CSS style zoom, although this does not work in all browsers e.g.

```
.zoomClassPercent {
zoom:150%;
}

.zoomClassRatio {
zoom:1.5;
}
```

Comment: Note that the icons will look horrible when you make them bigger.